# Docusign Envelopes: create ERROR 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ios, docusignapi

I have created a sandbox account for using Docusign APIs.  As a first step of it... [see the link of tutorial](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quickstart) I am trying to Send an electronic signature request via email (topic no. 4 in the link)

My request url and parameters are as specified. But it is giving ERROR 401 Unauthorized

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing in Request screenshot, you are I think passing IntegratorKey (16a82645-5c5a-****-****-***********) in the Authorization Header, which is wrong. In Authorization header you need to pass OAUTH token. You can generate OAUTH token with below steps:

There will be an **UnAuthenticate** link on the top of the page with green background, text will look like below

You are authenticated against the Demo environment. **Unauthenticate**,

So, can you please click "Unauthenticate", then it will show button as **"AUTHENTICATE USING SANDBOX ACCOUNT"**, once you click this button then a popup will come and it will have a blue button as **"GET OAUTH2 TOKEN"**, click this button, which will open a popup and ask you to enter your Demo/Sandbox credentials. Enter your credentials and then try above API call, it should work. If it does not may be some stale cookies/session will still send old credentials to DocuSign so then try it in Incognito or Inprivate browsing.