# API Error 401 - Error connecting to the API

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

We began seeing these DocuSign exceptions 09/24/2019:

```
DocuSign \ eSign \ ApiException (401)
[401] Error connecting to the API (https://NA3.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information)
```

None of the code surrounding our DocuSign logic has been touched for almost six months. So I'm at a loss as to why this exception is being thrown.

We're using the following packages (relating to this):

```
laravel/framework v5.8.35
docusign/esign-client 3.0.1
tucker-eric/docusign-rest-client 1.0.0
tucker-eric/laravel-docusign 0.1.1
```

I've tried to update the packages with composer thinking they might have made updates to fix something, but it didn't change anything other than throw `USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` instead of the exceptions' message above.

As I said, no code has been touched, and I have very little experience with the DocuSign API, *and* making matters worse this was an old developer's code...

I **am** able to hit the endpoint, and authenticate with our credentials, using Postman and it seems to work fine. So again, I'm not sure how this just started happening.

The code from our controller:

```php
$parcel = request('parcel_id');
$subdivision = $user->subdivision_id;
$subEmail = Subdivision::where('id', $user->subdivision_id)->pluck('email')->first();

$move = Move::create([
    'full_name' => request('full_name'),
    'email' => request('email'),
    'phone_number' => request('phone_number'),
    'parcel_id' => $parcel,
    'direction' => request('direction'),
    'action_date' => request('action_date'),
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'subdivision_id' => $subdivision
]);

$residentTabs = array(
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_ADDRESS_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->parcel->MailingAddress
    ),
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_DATE_RESIDENT_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->action_date->format('m/d/Y')
    ),
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_EMAIL_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->email
    ),
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_PRIMARY_PHONE_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->phone_number
    ),
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_FULL_NAME_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->full_name
    )
);

$pmTabs = array(
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_PM_ADDRESS_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->parcel->MailingAddress
    ),
    array(
        'tabLabel' => env('MOVE_IN_PM_DATE_FIELD'),
        'value' => $move->action_date->format('m/d/Y')
    ),
);

$templateRoles = array(
    array(
        'email' => $move->email,
        'name' => $move->full_name,
        'roleName' => 'Resident',
        'tabs' => array(
            'textTabs' => $residentTabs
        )
    ),
    array(
        'email' => $subEmail,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'roleName' => 'Property Manager',
        'tabs' => array(
            'textTabs' => $pmTabs
        )
    )
);

$envelopeDefinition = array(
    'status' => 'sent',
    'templateId' => env("DOCUSIGN_TEMPLATE_ID"),
    'templateRoles' => $templateRoles
);

$contract = DocuSign::get('envelopes')->createEnvelope($envelopeDefinition);
```

---

The last line is where the exception is thrown, and the function throwing the exceptions is:

`vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/ApiClient.php::callApi`

We expect it to work as it has, throwing no exceptions and creating the envelope successfully. 
However, we have been seeing `USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` and general `401` exceptions.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882458/docusign-envelopes-create-error-401-unauthorized

Comment: The issue appeared to be because DocuSign wasn't charging us for API access for the past year, but then we paid our annual invoice and lost access to the API. They have no idea how we had access apparently. It took us two phone calls (three hour calls...) to figure that out... to have them say they don't know. So I guess the issue is we have to pay for API access, even though we had it before with no issues.

Comment: So Inbar Gazit was kind of right ... maybe you should credit him as accepted answer, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token may have expired. Not sure how it was created and what authentication mechanism you are using. You need to check where is the token and the header in the REST API calls that is using it. It may be that was hardcoded, or was there a refresh token used to keep obtaining new tokens and that process broke.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an Authentication failure while trying to hit the `login_information` endpoint, it's likely that your application is using Legacy Header authentication with an invalid password.
I'd recommend the following:

- Try to log in to the web console at www.docusign.net, and perform a Password Reset if necessary
- Once you are able to log in, update the stored credentials in the application
- 2FA or forced Single Sign-On will both block Legacy Header auth. If either is in place, they will need to be disabled, or you will need to switch to one of the [Account Server auth workflows](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication).

Comment: We thought that too, thanks for that information though. I added a comment to my original post explaining what the problem was.